# Virtual Skeptics Episode #48

Tags: discussion

Another bit of advertising for Stack Exchange in [Episode #48 of Virtual Skeptics](http://virtualskeptics.com/2013/07/17/virtual-skeptics-48-17-july-2013/).  If you notice the shirt Tim is wearing (especially pointed out at 50:50), that was something that I gave him (also, Tim talks about a paper presented by my friend starting at about 42 minutes).

Comment: Tim is also a user here: [Tim Farley](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/284/tim-farley). Not sure about the other people in the hangout.